I have not received a single DMARC ruf report in 4 years
My DMARC record looks like:
"v=DMARC1; p=reject; rua=mailto:dmarc1@example.com; ruf=mailto:dmarc2@example.com; fo=1; adkim=s; aspf=s;"
I set it up 4 years ago. But I am yet to receive a single report on dmarc2@example.com.
Am I doing something wrong?

Have you sent a message to marc2@example.com to confirm the address is working correctly? Do you receive RUA reports? Do you have access to a server that would fail DMARC and can send one message to a server that you know supports sending RUF reports?

@Paul Manual email to dmarc2@example.com works. I receive RUA report. I don't have access to any server that's known for sending RUF reports

I don't like the final ";" after the spf setting. It's not necessary, but may not cause problem (not sure).
I also query whether a server will send you both a digest (rua) and single failure reports (ruf), but maybe you had no failures? That is to be hoped for after all :-) I suspect you can get one or the other, but not both, although again I'm not sure.
I'm also not clear on your meaning, with yet to receive a single report on dmarc2@example.com. The reports concern a domain, not a single email address within that domain. Does that match your understanding?
